# how can I install yarl in Docker?

Tags: python, docker

I get the following Runtime error when running my dockerfile.

"yarl 1.4+ requires Python 3.5+"

This happens when Docker tries to install the slackclient requirement for my image.

I already have python 3.8 installed on my machine.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty

RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install \
              python3 \
              python3-pip \
              make \
              build-essential \
              libssl-dev \
              zlib1g-dev \
              libbz2-dev \
              libreadline-dev \
              libsqlite3-dev \
              wget \
              curl \
              llvm \
              libncurses5-dev \
              zip \
              git-core \
              supervisor \
              sqlite

RUN mkdir -p /tmp
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

COPY deployment/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
RUN mkdir -p /opt/wwc
ADD . /opt/wwc/apartment-finder

RUN mkdir -p /opt/wwc/logs
WORKDIR /opt/wwc/apartment-finder

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Here is the full error message:

```
Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/yarl/setup.py) egg_info for package yarl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/yarl/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("yarl 1.4+ requires Python 3.5+")
RuntimeError: yarl 1.4+ requires Python 3.5+
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

File "/tmp/pip_build_root/yarl/setup.py", line 10, in <module>

raise RuntimeError("yarl 1.4+ requires Python 3.5+")

RuntimeError: yarl 1.4+ requires Python 3.5+
```

Comment: You should post your dockerfile so that we can better help you. The fact that you have python installed on your machine is irrelevant in this case. You need to install python in your image. This means adding the python installation commands in your dockerfile.

Comment: I see what you mean here. In that case it makes sense because the python install command int the docker file is probably installing an old python version. here is my dockerfile https://pastebin.com/vTVq7rhx
Could you please suggest a change so that the file installs python 3.7 or 3.8 instead of the current python 3 version ?

Comment: Use a newer base image, like `ubuntu:20.04` (ubuntu trusty is 14.04)

Comment: That looks like a pastebin URL, not a Dockerfile.  Can you edit your question to include the Dockerfile and not the URL?

Comment: @DavidMaze just edited the question. just to confirm again, changing the ubuntu version fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of python you have on your machine is not relevant to the problem. The problem is the version of python within the container you are trying to build. The container does not have access to your system's python.

Ubuntu Trusty Tahr is also known as 14.04. You can treat this version like a date -- this came out in April 2014. You shouldn't use 14.04 because it reached its end-of-life. Also, python 3.5 came out in September 2015 -- after the release of 14.04.

The solution, then, is to use a newer base image. You have many choices, but if you want to stick to ubuntu, then you can use the latest long-term-support (LTS) version, 20.04. To do this, change your `FROM` instruction to `FROM ubuntu:20.04`. Ubuntu 20.04 uses Python 3.8.